# Encrypted passwords in asp.net SQLMembershipProvider and Umbraco membership provider

Tags: asp.net, encryption, umbraco, sqlmembershipprovider

Security Noob here.

I am trying to move from asp.net membership to Umbraco membership. But using passwordFormat="Encrypted" seems to encrypt differently between the Umbraco membership provider and Microsoft's SQL membership provider.

If I register two users with the SQL membership provider (with passwordFormat="Encrypted") - the encoded passwords are different. If I do the same with the Umbraco provider they're the same.

While all the strings decrypt to the same thing (the correct password) - I apparently can't use the passwords encrypted by the SQL membership provider in the umbraco DB (ValidateUser fails).

Anyone have any ideas?

Note: I'm using the same machineKey on both sites.

Edit: Calling EncryptPassword() and EncodePassword() on the Umbraco membership provider gives different results - and EncodePassword is the correct one to call. But EncodePassword isn't available on the .NET Membership provider. This was another part of my confusion.

Comment: The passwords may be different because they are salted.  Check out the PasswordSalt column in the membership database, it should be a Base64 string.

Comment: @Infotekka after lots of thought I'm pretty sure that's it - because .NET has salts and Umbraco doesn't. I didn't realise encryption (not hashing) can use a salt (mainly because I didn't know how it could get back to the original plaintext without knowing the salt). And now doing a proper test - if I change the salt it will NOT let me log in. So that's it!

Comment: @Infotekka now I've checked, do you want to make this a real answer and I'll mark it correct - thanks for the clarity!

Comment: Right on, I copied my comment into an answer below - glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The passwords may be different because they are salted. Check out the PasswordSalt column in the membership database, it should be a Base64 string.

Answer (score 0):

The Umbraco passwords are hashed using the `System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1` class. I'm guessing you could hash the SQL membership users passwords with HMACSHA1 and call it good.

See [Add User with hashed password](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/users,-user-types-and-permissions/add-user-with-hashed-password) for more details.

Comment: It's using encryption, not hashing. I'm 100% sure of that because I can decrypt the DB strings (which would not be possible with hashes).

Comment: @IanGrainger, The `UmbracoMembershipProvider` has the `passwordFormat` set to `Hashed` by default unless you've set it to `Encrypted`.

Comment: Yes, I had used Encrypted.